# Magento Fatal Error after upgrading OrderMonitor

Tags: magento, fatal-error

I am running Magento 1.8.0 and tried upgrading OrderMonitor extension via Connect.  I had the create backup option checked and it was running the backup for a while so I stepped away from laptop for a while.  When I came back laptop was frozen and I had to restart.  I'm not sure if this affected the backup process or messed something up somehow or if the extension itself is the culprit.  When I go to the site now www.streetstrider.com or try to access the admin panel I get the following error:

Fatal error: Class Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::insertIgnore, Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::changeTableAutoIncrement) in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3864

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.  If you need any other information, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: sorry Enigmativity, will post it there.  thanks